# Lazy load изображений + индексация поисковиками

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, lazyloading

Есть код, который подгружает изображения на странице после загрузки самой страницы:

```js
$('img[data-src]').each(function() {
  var img = $(this);
  img.attr('src',img.attr('data-src'));
  img.on('load', function() {
    img.removeAttr('data-src');
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  width:100%;
  transition:opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  opacity:1;
}

img[data-src] {
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img data-src="https://forums.macrumors.com/attachments/el-capitan_desktop_2560x1440-jpg.559881/" alt="" />
```

Как видим отсюда, url картинки указан в `data-src`. Помогите разобраться в вопросе - индексируются ли они в этом случае? На различных форумах и сервисах вопросов/ответов мнения расходятся. Кто-то говорит, что индексируется все, у чего есть url. Кто-то - что для индексации обязателен `src`. Кто же прав?

И, если `src` все таки необходим для индекса, есть ли способ на js (возможно, с jQuery) организовать следующий сценарий:

1. Изначально указываем в html `src` для изображений
2. ДО ЗАГРУЗКИ этих изображений копируем url в `data-src`
3. После загрузки страницы возвращаем `src`, используя код выше

Всем заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вроде как роботы парсят страницу с выполнением скриптов на ней. Вы можете проверить свою страницу, запросив для неё "Посмотреть как видит робот" в Google Webmasters.

Answer (score 3):

Не претендую на правильный ответ, но для справки. Технически для поисковиков можно предоставлять отдельную версию сайта на чистом html, без css и js. По заголовку `user agent` определять, является ли запрашивающий поисковиком-ботом, а затем можно проверить ip бота по dns. И отправить облегченную версию сайта. Вот к примеру `user agent` поисковика Google Bot https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943 и проверка ip Google bot https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80553?hl=ru .

Comment: Я так понимаю, это делается на php? к сожалению, не силен в нем. А для чего еще проверять ip, если в user agent видно, что это бот? Если даже кому-то нужно было подделать это, то ему и не обязательно выдавать основную версию сайта, не так ли? Вообще, 
как поисковики относятся к такой схеме или это разрешенная (или не запрещенная) практика?

Comment: @Cheg иногда это не то что разрешено, а просто необходимо.

Comment: @Cheg поисковики, не поддерживающие js не смогут прочитать атрибут `data-src`, и сценарий такой организовать вряд ли получится, так как браузер начнет загружать изображения раньше, чем произойдет событие `window.onload`.

Comment: Всё это очень смахивает на клоакинг, что уж точно не приветствуется поисковиками.