# Не показывать изображение пока оно не загрузилось

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Приветствую.

Думаю, многие знают о том, как не красиво выглядит загрузка большого изображения. Оно загружается и отображается по кускам сверху вниз. Это не очень приятно, не очень красиво.

Конечно, есть прелоадеры и, возможно, другое решение, но вот в чем вопрос:

**Как сделать так, чтобы изображение не отображалось на странице, пока оно полностью не загрузится?**

То есть будет сначала отображаться страница с текстом, потому что она весит меньше и потом будут отображаться все изображения или сколько их там, но каждое из них будет показываться (отображаться) после того, как полностью загрузилось.

Помогите.

Comment: Так а чем вариант с lazyload не подходит вам?

Comment: https://appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/

Comment: Если картинка одна или пускай несколько то по мне достаточно их сжать. А если большой список картинок то можно реализовать подгрузку картинок по событию scroll.

Comment: Ответ есть в моем вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/685804/lazy-load-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8 - там рабочий вариант

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте этот код:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = your_photo_path; // здесь начинается загрузка изображения
img.onload = function() {
    // устанавливаем новое изображение в photo_wrap
    document.getElementById('photo_wrap').innerHTML = '<img id="your_photo" src="' + your_photo_path + '">';
}
```

Для начала мы создаем объект `img` и без изменения текущего DOM страницы загружаем в него изображение. После загрузки изображение попадает в кэш браузера и срабатывает `img.onload`, а далее много путей. В приведенном примере было загружен тег с изображением в контейнер для фотографии `photo_wrap`, но можно и просто менять атрибут `src` или грузить изображение в `background`.