# Загрузка изображений, сначала плохого качество, потом лучше

Tags: javascript, html

Как реализовать загрузку изображений, чтобы сначала отображались изображения плохого качества (для быстроты), а когда подгрузятся хорошие, то хорошего

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/165645/

Comment: Вот же практически готовый [код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/685804/256824) в несколько строк